# RESTful api method to verify user's email id , activate account and reset password

Tags: node.js, rest, restful-authentication

I want to send a link to the email address for account verification and to reset the password. Later I had a frontend+backend structure, I want to know how can I do this in REST api way. If I host 2 frontend app in https://example1.com and https://example2.com how can I write a flexible backend in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1: Sending Emails**

To send emails, you need to have an SMTP server. For SMTP server, you can either configure one by your own or subscribe for email services like sendgrid. 
Sendgrid provides APIs, which allows you to send transactional or promotional emails.

**Part 2: Middleware**

You may have to rent a linux server, install Node JS on it and use Express JS for developing and deploying the backend with REST API support. Your frontend apps https://example1.com and https://example2.com can be hosted using Apache and they can communicate to the middleware which is developed using Express JS.

**Part 2: Database Connectivity from Middleware**

You can install MariaDB in server and connect your node js program to MariaDB using the node module *mysql*.

This is just a high level advice. You will have to spend some time yourself to get everything configured and wired, or take the help of experienced engineers.